Keras Model Loading Issue
I have downloaded a model .keras file and when trying to load it im getting this error,
ValueError: Unrecognized keyword arguments passed to ConvLSTM2D: 
{'batch_input_shape': [None, 5, 240, 240, 3], 'time_major': False}

This is my code as it gave some other errors before adding that custom_objects, i asked chat gpt and added some to it.
from keras.models import load_model
from keras.layers import LeakyReLU
from keras.initializers import Orthogonal
from keras.layers import ConvLSTM2D
from keras.models import Sequential

custom_objects = {'LeakyReLU': LeakyReLU, 'Orthogonal': Orthogonal, 'ConvLSTM2D': ConvLSTM2D}

model = load_model('./Models/CNN_Model.keras', custom_objects=custom_objects)

I need to load this model, that is enough for now.
